# How do I mutate a value in a genetic algorithm using Gaussian distribution?

Tags: algorithms, statistics, genetic-algorithms

I've been reading 'Introduction to Evolutionary Algorithms'. This method is stated, but not described, and I can't find anything more specific online. p44/45 of 2nd Ed for reference.

> adding to the current gene value an amount drawn randomly from a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and user-specified standard deviation

Would be great to get the step by step, from initial to mutated value, including how Gaussian distribution works (or a link to something that could fill that gap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gaussian distribution is that favorite curve from math and stats also known as the bell curve or a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

An example of this can be seen with the sum of rolling 10x 10 sided dice:
[image: 10d10]

<sup>From [AnyDice](http://anydice.com) `output 10d10`</sup>

What this means is that the amount of mutation for a gene is most likely very little.  If you roll this set of dice 30 times, you'll get some data that looks like:

53, 38, 52, 62, 51, 50, 71, 44, 52, 55, 56, 45, 48, 67, 48, 63, 33, 40, 62, 60, 54, 48, 67, 60, 44, 63, 50, 50, 64, 56

Notice that most of these numbers are fairly close to the value of 55.  Thats the key to this - you want a middle value.

When doing a mutation on a gene that has a possible change of -10 .. +10 you want most of the chance to be about 0.  Maybe some 1s, or 2s, or -1s, or -2s... but you don't want a +10 to have an equal chance of a mutation as a +1.

So? How do you do this?

In Java, one would use [java.util.Random#nextGaussian()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()).  That will give you a number that has a normal distribution with a mean of 0.0.

You would take the value you get from `nextGaussian()`, and then... well, do math to it to get it into the range you want.  Just because you're getting a number with a mean of 0.0 doesn't mean that any given value will be in a certain range.

The specifics of the `nextGaussian()` for your chosen language is just a matter of finding the right library for the language.  Its there somewhere.  You may wish to browse the [tag: normal-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normal-distribution) on Stack Overflow filtered for your language to see if any of those questions specifically help you.